# javascript slider with thumbnail not working with both options

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, slider

I make an image slider with text and thumbnail as well.
the issue is when I click the thumbnail its shows the photo correctly no issue but when I click the next button then click on the thumbnail then slider not working below is the code.

I used two arrays

1. for images
2. for text

then the next() and Previous() function to change the image when clicking on the next and previous button.

```js
var images = ['<img src="images/1.jpg"width = 100%; height=500px;  >',
  '<img src="images/2.jpg"width = 100%; height=500px; >',
  '<img src="images/3.jpg" width = 100%; height=500px;>'
];
var text = ["Missing From Karachi", "Missing From Peshawer", "Missing From Lahore"];
var i = 0;
var x = document.getElementById("demo");
var y = document.getElementById("text");

function next() {
  i++;

  if (i < images.length) {
    x.innerHTML = images[i];
    y.innerHTML = text[i];

  } else {
    i = 0;
    x.innerHTML = images[i];
    y.innerHTML = text[i];
  }

}


function prev() {
  i--;
  if (i >= 0) {
    x.innerHTML = images[i];
    y.innerHTML = text[i];
  } else {
    i = images.length - 1;

    x.innerHTML = images[i];
    y.innerHTML = text[i];

  }

}

function thumbchange(num) {
  var thumb = 'images/' + num + '.jpg';
  document.getElementById("demo1").src = thumb;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">

  <p class="text" id="demo"><img id="demo1" src="images/1.jpg" width=100%; height=500px;> </p>

  <div class="onebtn">
    <button id="btn1" class="btn1 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" class="prev" onclick="prev()">PREVIOUS</button>
  </div>

  <div class="twobtn">
    <button id="btn2" class="btn2 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="button" class="next" onclick="next()">NEXT</button>
  </div>

  <p id="text" class="text" style="font-size:40px; font-weight:bolder;">Missing From Karachi</p>

  <br><br>

  <ul class="thumbs">
    <li class="img12" onclick="thumbchange(1)"><img src="images/1.jpg" width=100%;></li>
    <li class="img12" onclick="thumbchange(2)"><img src="images/2.jpg"></li>
    <li class="img12" onclick="thumbchange(3)"><img src="images/3.jpg"></li>
  </ul>

</div>
```

see the example
https://codepen.io/pen/?template=WNxebOO

Comment: Please post a snippet reproducing your issue, with demo data.

Comment: @IslamElshobokshy 
https://codepen.io/pen/?template=WNxebOO
check this